# AWS SQS boto3 send_message returns 'dict' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Tags: python, amazon-sqs

- I am new to python and I am still learning it.
- I am writing a python code to send a message to AWS SQS
- Following is the code I have written

  > `from boto3.session import Session
  >   session = Session(aws_access_key_id='**', aws_secret_access_key='**',
  >   region_name='us-west-2') 
  >   clientz = session.client('sqs') 
  >   queue = clientz.get_queue_url(QueueName='queue_name') 
  >   print queue responses = queue.send_message(MessageBody='Test')
  >   print(response.get('MessageId'))`

  - On running this code it returns

  > {u'QueueUrl': 'https://us-west-2.queue.amazonaws.com/@@/queue_name', '                                                 ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': '@@'}}
  >
  > Traceback (most recent call last):
  >   File "publisher_dropbox.py", line 77, in 
  >       responses = queue.send_message(MessageBody='Test')
  >
  > AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'send_message'
- I am not sure what the 'dict' object is,  since I haven't specified that anywhere.

Comment: `dict` is a built-in type in Python that maps a value to another (think of it as something like a phonebook). You might want to check out boto's API [here](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/sqs.html). Also check out an example [here](https://gist.github.com/philchristensen/6452581).

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am a Java person, so can I think of it like the Class where dict belongs to doesn't have the method send_message()?

Comment: That's right. And, the key issue here is actually that you are calling `send_message()` on the wrong object. If you looked at the API spec I sent over, `send_message()` should be called on a *sqs connection* instead of a queue.

Answer (score 5):

I think you mix up the boto3 client send_mesasge  [Boto3 client send_message](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.send_message) with the boto3.resource.sqs ability.

First, for boto3.client.sqs.send_message, you need to specify QueueUrl. Secondly, the the error message appear because you write incorrect print statement.

```
# print() function think anything follow by the "queue" are some dictionary attributes  
print queue responses = queue.send_message(MessageBody='Test')
```

In addition, I don't need to use boto3.session unless I need to explicitly define alternate profile or access other than setup inside aws credential files.

```
import boto3 
sqs = boto3.client('sqs') 
queue = sqs.get_queue_url(QueueName='queue_name')
# get_queue_url will return a dict e.g.
# {'QueueUrl':'......'}
# You cannot mix dict and string in print. Use the handy string formatter
# will fix the problem   
print "Queue info : {}".format(queue)

responses = sqs.send_message(QueueUrl= queue['QueueUrl'], MessageBody='Test')
# send_message() response will return dictionary  
print "Message send response : {} ".format(response)
```